# Change Cassandra datacenter name

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to change the datacenter name in a Cassandra Cluster?
If so how do I accomplish this? I have a Dev cluster which was built with the default DC name 'Cassandra'. I would like to change this because we are going to be setting up and testing replication between DCs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its possible you can change the snitch to GossipingFilePropertySnitch and specify the dc name and rack name in `cassandra-rackdc.properties` file, After doing that you need to restart the node, in that case you will get an error like :

```
Error: Cannot start node if snitch's data center (<new-datacentername>) differs from previous data center (<old-datacenter-name>). 
Please fix the snitch configuration, decommission and rebootstrap this node or use the flag -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true.
```

In order to avoid this need to add the below line in `cassandra-env.sh` file and restart the node.

```
JVM_OPTS=\"$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.ignore_rack=true -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true\"'
```

Remember, you will need downtime for your cluster to restart your datacenter in this case if doing this on production environment.

Comment: Is there a way to change the data center name without enabling the ignore_rack or ignore_dc options? Does enabling these options have any additional negative effects on the Cassandra cluster?

Comment: Earlier changing datacenter/rack was allowed  but it is disabled since around 2.1+ cassandra version. 

This is essentially because if snitch configuration is changed, it may have stale data present depending on token values and snitch settings and there is a risk of node reporting invalid/ missing data to client, therefore the error message. 

As you said that its about a Dev cluster, it should not be an issue, but you may need to be a bit careful.